# Creating and linking subdomain in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have a rails app running using unicorn. 
**example.com.**
Which runs fine. I have a wordpress blog running using apache2. I want this wordpress blog 
to use **blog.example.com.** I have created the sub domain using Route 53.But How should i link blog.example.com to the wordpress blog? Any hint will be useful.

Comment: You would use virtual hosts. How you do that depends on your web server

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that NameVirtualHosts is enabled and then you can start a new virtual host with the VirtualHost Directive, such as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.site
        ServerName subdomain.site
```

And finish off the VirtualHost directive as you see fit.